# StatementInvalid : Could not find table while creating model object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've just started programming using Instant rails and don't know much about it. So, I've made a rails project and created a database name contactlist_development and a table named contacts with some fields. I've generated a model named Contact and started the rails console using "ruby script/console".

But when i tried making a new Contact model object, it displays StatementInvalid : could not find the table 'contacts'.

[image]

Comment: You need to do `rake db:migrate`.

Answer (score 0):

Running rake db:migrate will execute the code you generated, hence creating the table.

Hope this helps!

Comment: i think it worked. But when I tried to assingn a value to the element using (my_contact.first_name = 'Luffy'). An error occurs saying undefined method first_name.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used **rails generate model contact** command to make Contact model? If yes, you forget to run command :

**rake db:migrate**

Or you can make table directly by creating migration or using sql query.